How do I access EnvironmentValues (RequestReviewAction) in MAUI iOS (formerly Xamarin iOS)?
My code for requesting review is using SKStoreReviewController and it is obsolete in iOS 18.0. The new guide tells me to use RequestReviewAction but I have no idea how to access it since it uses a strange SwiftUI notation I do not know. Asking AI didn't help as well though it seems to be something to do with injection.
How do I translate this code into MAUI C#?
@Environment(\.requestReview) private var requestReview


About:
@Environment(\.requestReview) private var requestReview

You can refer to this case: @Environment vs @EnvironmentObject.

How do I access EnvironmentValues (RequestReviewAction) in MAUI iOS (formerly Xamarin iOS)?

The more important point is: The iOS18 API for Xcode16 is not currently supported. And you can follow up this issue: [META] Xcode 16.0 Support for .NET 8/9 and MAUI #20802

Sorry I have 0 knowledge of SwiftUI, is it correct to say @Environment is a new iOS 18 API and I should not be worried about it for now?

Yes, you got it.

Thanks, I will delay supporting it for now. We plan to skip .NET 9 and just go straight to .NET 10 later. We will ignore the warning for now.

Now that the issue linked has been closed, could you give me a reference on how to do it please? Is it possible in .NET 8?

Is it possible in .NET 8? You can see the link of last comment and this comment. It skipped .NET 8.
